# encrypt the form parameters and send it over url and then decrypt and open required page using spring mvc

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

how can i encrypt the form parameters and send it over url and then decrypt and open required page using spring mvc ??

this is my main form page

```
<html>
<form:form action="go/show" method="get" target="_blank" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><label>Application Name:</label></td>
            <td class="field"><form:input path="appnames"  name="appname"        value="test" id="appname"/></td>
        </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

from this parameter go to getter and setters 
and then to controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView form() {


     return new ModelAndView("form","command",new Credentials());
}

  @RequestMapping(value = "/go/show", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public ModelAndView show(@ModelAttribute("credentials") Credentials credentials()
{
        return new ModelAndView("go/show")}
```

where as show is my landing jsp

my URL shows like localhost:8080/go/show?appnames=test
and shows my landing page show.jsp

no Https is not an option and whenever i am trying to redirect url to something like localhost:8080/go/show?cjavs%20cknbs= it shows page not found ... after that how to show the desired page

Comment: If using HTTPS is an option, it is already done without further action from you...

Comment: no Https is not an option and whenever i am trying to redirect url to something like 
localhost:8080/go/show?cjavs%20cknbs=
it shows page not found ...


after that how to show the desired page , Can anyone help

Answer (score -1):

- If you don't wanna send your params in the url you should use POST instead of GET method.
- If you need encrypt the value of your params you must use a key pair and a cipher algorithm (RSA for example).
- If you want obfuscate your params (I can't see a reason for do that) you can easily transform to Base64 (for example) but you should encode the name and the value separatedly and be aware of url-encode it, because you can't use special chars like "+", "/", "=".

Comment: only option i have is send parameters in GET in hav done obfuscate of param ,encrypt them , now i want to get them decrypted ,but donot know where should it do decrypt